# having trouble running auto-py-to-exe

Tags: auto-py-to-exe

I was having trouble running auto-py-to-exe and after executing, this will appear.
I'm not sure if any of my installed packages are cause for this issue. I tried to reinstall but still this problem will appear. What can I do to fix this?

C:\Users\Admin>auto-py-to-exe

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
> "**main**", mod_spec)

> File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)

> File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe_*main*_.py", line 5, in

> File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe_*main*_.py", line 10, in

> from . import ui
> File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\ui.py", line 5, in

> import eel
> File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\eel_*init*_.py", line 13, in

> import pyparsing as pp
> File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyparsing_*init*_.py", line 130, in

> **version** = **version_info**.**version**
> AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '**version**'